# Spring boot, How do I remove items in a list using Jpa or ReactiveCrud?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa

Suppose I have an entity like this

```
@Document
data class Restaurant(
  @Id
  val restaurantId: String,
  val pendingOrder: List<String>,
  val receivedOrder: List<String>
)
```

and I want to remove all elements in a list. when I'm using ReactiveCurd, I usually do it this way

```
restaurantRepository
  .findById(restaurantId)
  .map {
    it.copy(
      receivedOrder = listOf(),
      pendingOrder = listOf()
    )
  }
  .flatMap { restaurantRepository.save(it) }
  .block()!!
```

but then I realized, is this wrong? because I didn't even release the allocated memory I just create a new empty list and attached to the property, will this caused some memory leaked? so how do I remove an element from a list in the properway.

Comment: Q: You have some other entity out there for your pendingOrders, and for your receivedOrders, correct?  There are (at least) three tables in your DB: restaurants, pendingOrders, and receivedOrders, correct?

Comment: @paulsm4 sorry it should be just a list of string.